# W10 calling native Bluetooth API BluetoothGATTGetServices issue

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am running on W10 Version 21H2 (OS Build 19044.1766).
I need to call BluetoothGATTGetServices (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothleapis/nf-bluetoothleapis-bluetoothgattgetservices).
I am using an android phone to connect to the W10 computer over bluetooth.
The android phone connects and pairs to the W10 computer and I can transfer/send files to the android phone from windows.

The ultimate goal is to get information about the bluetooth device that is connecting to the windows computer for a security product (see https://www.squadratechnologies.com).
Specifically, I would like to get the bluetooth devices serialnumber and other information that can be logged for security analysis.

Before attempting to call BluetoothGATTGetServices, I first successfully am calling BluetoothEnumerateInstalledServices (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothenumerateinstalledservices).
From calling BluetoothEnumerateInstalledServices, I get the following 14 GUIDs (representing the services ???):
00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

6d761db8-c9e9-4615-920c-e1cee4c2494d

a23d00bc-217c-123b-9c00-fc44577136ee

0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

00001115-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

00001116-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

Now, when I run the sysinternals WinObj utility, I can see a symbolic link in the GLOBAL?? namespace of:
BTHENUM#{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}_VID&00010075_PID&0100#7&39ffa139&0&F0F56456EDD3_C00000000#{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
where xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx is one of the 14 GUIDs listed above.

So, to make a call to BluetoothGATTGetServices, I need to first call the win32 API of CreateFile (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea)
against one of the 14 symbolic links in the GLOBAL?? namespace to get an open HANDLE (which is parameter 1 for BluetoothGATTGetServices).

The actual string I am passing to CreateFile looks like:
\?\BTHENUM#{00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_VID&00010075_PID&0100#7&39ffa139&0&F0F56456EDD3_C00000000#{00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}
where xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx = 00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (for example).

The results from a call to CreateFile for each of the 14 GUIDs is (see the error code at the end of the line):
\?\BTHENUM#{00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_VID&00010075_PID&0100#7&39ffa139&0&F0F56456EDD3_C00000000#{00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb} 32: The request is not supported.

\?\BTHENUM#{0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_VID&00010075_PID&0100#7&39ffa139&0&F0F56456EDD3_C00000000#{0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb} 2: The system cannot find the file specified.

\?\BTHENUM#{00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_VID&00010075_PID&0100#7&39ffa139&0&F0F56456EDD3_C00000000#{00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb} 32: The request is not supported.

\?\BTHENUM#{00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_VID&00010075_PID&0100#7&39ffa139&0&F0F56456EDD3_C00000000#{00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb} 32: The request is not supported.

\?\BTHENUM#{6d761db8-c9e9-4615-920c-e1cee4c2494d}_VID&00010075_PID&0100#7&39ffa139&0&F0F56456EDD3_C00000000#{6d761db8-c9e9-4615-920c-e1cee4c2494d} 32: The request is not supported.

\?\BTHENUM#{a23d00bc-217c-123b-9c00-fc44577136ee}_VID&00010075_PID&0100#7&39ffa139&0&F0F56456EDD3_C00000000#{a23d00bc-217c-123b-9c00-fc44577136ee} 32: The request is not supported.

\?\BTHENUM#{0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_VID&00010075_PID&0100#7&39ffa139&0&F0F56456EDD3_C00000000#{0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb} 5: Access is denied.

\?\BTHENUM#{0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_VID&00010075_PID&0100#7&39ffa139&0&F0F56456EDD3_C00000000#{0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb} 5: Access is denied.

\?\BTHENUM#{00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_VID&00010075_PID&0100#7&39ffa139&0&F0F56456EDD3_C00000000#{00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb} 32: The request is not supported.

\?\BTHENUM#{00001115-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_VID&00010075_PID&0100#7&39ffa139&0&F0F56456EDD3_C00000000#{00001115-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb} 32: The request is not supported.

\?\BTHENUM#{00001116-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_VID&00010075_PID&0100#7&39ffa139&0&F0F56456EDD3_C00000000#{00001116-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb} 32: The request is not supported.

\?\BTHENUM#{0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_VID&00010075_PID&0100#7&39ffa139&0&F0F56456EDD3_C00000000#{0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb} 2: The system cannot find the file specified.

\?\BTHENUM#{0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_VID&00010075_PID&0100#7&39ffa139&0&F0F56456EDD3_C00000000#{0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb} 32: The request is not supported.

\?\BTHENUM#{00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_VID&00010075_PID&0100#7&39ffa139&0&F0F56456EDD3_C00000000#{00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb} 32: The request is not supported.

I variable-ized the parameters to CreateFile thinking they might influence the opening of the symbolic links (above) using:
DWORD dwDesiredAccess[] = {
GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
GENERIC_READ
};
DWORD dwShareMode[] = {
FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
FILE_SHARE_READ,
FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE
};
DWORD dwCreationDisposition[] = {
OPEN_EXISTING
};
DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes[] = {
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED
};
but none of the combinations worked.

2 of the 14 symbolic links failed with 'Access is denied'.
They are:
\?\BTHENUM#{0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_VID&00010075_PID&0100#7&39ffa139&0&F0F56456EDD3_C00000000#{0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}
\?\BTHENUM#{0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_VID&00010075_PID&0100#7&39ffa139&0&F0F56456EDD3_C00000000#{0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}

Looking at the security DACL for these symbolic links is:
For Administrators and SYSTEM, they are allowed to: Delete, 'Change permissions', 'Change owner'.
So, the only way to get to the resource is to take ownership which seems not right to me.
Furthermore, when I did try to take ownership (experimenting on how to fix this issue), it failed because the resource was 'opened by another process'.

I have also used the approach to get a device path using an interface GUID (using the Setup and CM_xx apis) which does let me open a HANDLE:
#define BLUETOOTH_INTERFACE_GUID  "{781aee18-7733-4ce4-add0-91f41c67b592}"
\?\bthle#dev_f0f56456edd3#7&29e54a1a&0&f0f56456edd3#{781aee18-7733-4ce4-add0-91f41c67b592}
however, the call to BluetoothGATTGetServices fails with:
HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_NOT_FOUND) : Element not found.

Searching around does show code (GetBLEHandle):
https://gist.github.com/programmarchy/c9d02e22d58bfab3f8bb
but I think this must have worked on a windows release prior to W10.

I see Microsoft developed code in WinRT (class library) that is supposed to let you access the Bluetooth GATT service but I need to use native code and this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothleapis/) says it is possible.

Any help you be greatly appreciated, thank you very much.

Hi Mike,

So, as painful as it is :-), I think I will try to use the win32 Setup API to find the services handler first.
Thank you for the link...
It seems to be a 'software framework product' but nevertheless, it has some good information and I will continue to study it.

Do you know what the GUID is for the bluetooth le devices' service handler?
It looks like these GUIDs are predefined by bluetooth.org (which I am trying to get joined to now) but I am having a heck of a time finding these hard coded values.

Through windows message eventing, I have all the info about the parent radio and have the bluetooth le device address.
If I stick to win32, does it mean I will need to open a socket to the device to communicate with the GATT service?
I was hoping that the win32 bluetoothleapis were going to abstract the tcp/ip coding away but perhaps not.

Thanks again, I know these are newbie questions but you gotta start somewhere! :-)

Well, I "think" for bluetooth LE, to get the GATT service, we might need to code up some Bluetooth TCP/IP...see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/bluetooth/bluetooth-and-wsalookupservicebegin-for-service-discovery

I have made it a bit further now (still a work in progress) and seem to be pulling the services from the android phone now using:

```
BOOL CSecRMMBlueToothSocket::GetService(
    TCHAR* pTCHARDeviceName_in)
{
    INT l_INTPropertyCount = 0;

    if (m_BOOLWSAStartupCalled == FALSE)
    {
        CallWSAStartup();
    }

    if (m_BOOLWSAStartupCalled == TRUE)
    {
        if (m_BOOLHaveSOCKADDR_BTH == FALSE)
        {
            GetDeviceSOCKADDR_BTH(pTCHARDeviceName_in);
        }
    }

    if ((m_BOOLWSAStartupCalled == TRUE) &&
        (m_BOOLHaveSOCKADDR_BTH == TRUE))
    {
        TCHAR l_TCHARWSAAddressToString[40] = { 0 };
        DWORD l_DWORDLength = sizeof(l_TCHARWSAAddressToString);

        // If no error occurs, WSAAddressToString returns a value of zero. 
        // Otherwise, the value SOCKET_ERROR is returned, and a specific error number 
        // can be retrieved by calling WSAGetLastError.
        INT l_INTReturnCode =
            WSAAddressToString(
                // we got m_SOCKADDR_BTH from call to method
                // GetSOCKADDR_BTH.
                (LPSOCKADDR)&m_SOCKADDR_BTH,
                (DWORD)sizeof(SOCKADDR_BTH),
                NULL,
                l_TCHARWSAAddressToString,
                (LPDWORD)&l_DWORDLength);

        if (l_INTReturnCode == 0)
        {
            ULONG l_ULONGSizeOfWSAQUERYSET = sizeof(WSAQUERYSET);
            PWSAQUERYSET l_PWSAQUERYSET =
                (PWSAQUERYSET)
                HeapAlloc(
                    GetProcessHeap(),
                    HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY,
                    l_ULONGSizeOfWSAQUERYSET);

            if (l_PWSAQUERYSET != NULL)
            {
                GUID l_GUIDToLookup = PublicBrowseGroupServiceClass_UUID;
                ULONG  l_ULONGControlFlags = LUP_RETURN_ALL;
                HANDLE l_HANDLELookup = NULL;
                DWORD l_DWORDSizeOfWSAQUERYSET = (DWORD)l_ULONGSizeOfWSAQUERYSET;

                ZeroMemory(l_PWSAQUERYSET, l_ULONGSizeOfWSAQUERYSET);

                l_PWSAQUERYSET->dwNameSpace = NS_BTH;
                l_PWSAQUERYSET->dwSize = l_DWORDSizeOfWSAQUERYSET;
                l_PWSAQUERYSET->dwNumberOfCsAddrs = 0;
                l_PWSAQUERYSET->lpszContext = l_TCHARWSAAddressToString;
                l_PWSAQUERYSET->lpServiceClassId = &l_GUIDToLookup;

                for (INT l_INTRetryCount = 0;
                    l_INTRetryCount < CXN_MAX_INQUIRY_RETRY;
                    l_INTRetryCount++)
                {
                    BOOL l_BOOLContinueLookup = FALSE;

                    l_ULONGControlFlags = LUP_RETURN_ALL;
                    if (l_INTRetryCount != 0)
                    {
                        l_ULONGControlFlags |= LUP_FLUSHCACHE;
                        Sleep(CXN_DELAY_NEXT_INQUIRY * 1000);
                    }

                    INT l_INTWSALookupServiceBegin =
                        WSALookupServiceBegin(
                            l_PWSAQUERYSET,
                            l_ULONGControlFlags,
                            &l_HANDLELookup);

                    if ((l_INTWSALookupServiceBegin == NO_ERROR) &&
                        (l_HANDLELookup != NULL))
                    {
                        l_BOOLContinueLookup = TRUE;
                    }
                    else
                    if (l_INTRetryCount > 0)
                    {
                        // TODO:
                        // wprintf(L"=CRITICAL= | WSALookupServiceBegin() failed with error code %d, WSAGetLastError = %d\n", iResult, WSAGetLastError());
                        break;
                    }

                    while (l_BOOLContinueLookup == TRUE) {
                        INT l_INTWSALookupServiceNext =
                            WSALookupServiceNext(
                                l_HANDLELookup,
                                l_ULONGControlFlags,
                                &l_DWORDSizeOfWSAQUERYSET,
                                l_PWSAQUERYSET);

                        if (l_INTWSALookupServiceNext == NO_ERROR)
                        {
                            ATL::CAtlString l_CAtlStringServiceInstanceName =
                                l_PWSAQUERYSET->lpszServiceInstanceName;
                            if (l_CAtlStringServiceInstanceName.GetLength() != 0)
                            {
                                psecRMM_BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SERVICE l_psecRMM_BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SERVICE =
                                    new secRMM_BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SERVICE();
                                if (l_psecRMM_BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SERVICE != NULL)
                                {
                                    l_psecRMM_BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SERVICE->serviceInstanceComment =
                                    l_PWSAQUERYSET->lpszComment;

                                    CSADDR_INFO* l_pCSADDR_INFO =
                                        (CSADDR_INFO*)l_PWSAQUERYSET->lpcsaBuffer;

                                    l_psecRMM_BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SERVICE->serviceInstanceCSADDR_INFO.iProtocol =
                                        l_pCSADDR_INFO->iProtocol;
                                    l_psecRMM_BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SERVICE->serviceInstanceCSADDR_INFO.iSocketType =
                                        l_pCSADDR_INFO->iSocketType;
                                    l_psecRMM_BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SERVICE->serviceInstanceCSADDR_INFO.LocalAddr =
                                        l_pCSADDR_INFO->LocalAddr;
                                    l_psecRMM_BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SERVICE->serviceInstanceCSADDR_INFO.RemoteAddr =
                                        l_pCSADDR_INFO->RemoteAddr;

                                    l_psecRMM_BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SERVICE->serviceInstanceGUID.Data1 =
                                        l_PWSAQUERYSET->lpServiceClassId->Data1;
                                    l_psecRMM_BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SERVICE->serviceInstanceGUID.Data2 =
                                        l_PWSAQUERYSET->lpServiceClassId->Data2;
                                    l_psecRMM_BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SERVICE->serviceInstanceGUID.Data3 =
                                        l_PWSAQUERYSET->lpServiceClassId->Data3;
                                    strncpy((char*)l_psecRMM_BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SERVICE->serviceInstanceGUID.Data4,
                                            (char*)l_PWSAQUERYSET->lpServiceClassId->Data4, 8);

                                    m_mapOfBluetoothDeviceServices.insert(
                                        std::pair<ATL::CAtlString, psecRMM_BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SERVICE>
                                        (l_CAtlStringServiceInstanceName,
                                            l_psecRMM_BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SERVICE));

                                    l_INTPropertyCount++;
                                }
                            }                           
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            INT l_INTWSAGetLastError =
                                WSAGetLastError();
                            if (l_INTWSAGetLastError == WSA_E_NO_MORE)
                            {
                                l_BOOLContinueLookup = FALSE;
                            }
                            else
                            if (l_INTWSAGetLastError == WSAEFAULT)
                            {
                                // The buffer for QUERYSET was insufficient.
                                // In such case 3rd parameter "ulPQSSize" of function "WSALookupServiceNext()" receives
                                // the required size.  So we can use this parameter to reallocate memory for QUERYSET.
                                HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, l_PWSAQUERYSET);

                                l_PWSAQUERYSET =
                                    (PWSAQUERYSET)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(),
                                        HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY,
                                        l_DWORDSizeOfWSAQUERYSET);

                                if (l_PWSAQUERYSET == NULL)
                                {
                                    //wprintf(L"!ERROR! | Unable to allocate memory for WSAQERYSET\n");
                                    l_INTWSALookupServiceNext = STATUS_NO_MEMORY;
                                    l_BOOLContinueLookup = FALSE;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //wprintf(L"=CRITICAL= | WSALookupServiceNext() failed with error code %d\n", iResult);
                                l_BOOLContinueLookup = FALSE;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    WSALookupServiceEnd(l_HANDLELookup);
                }

                HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, l_PWSAQUERYSET);
                l_PWSAQUERYSET = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        else
        {
            INT l_INTWSAGetLastError = WSAGetLastError();
        }
    }

return(l_INTPropertyCount);
}
```

However, I still am unclear about getting the GATT service which I don't see from the list of services returned from using:

```
GUID l_GUIDToLookup = PublicBrowseGroupServiceClass_UUID;
```

also, I am not seeing the GUIDs come back from the services returned so I think I might need to mess with the control flag on the WSAQUERYSET.

Here are the services coming back from the android phone:

"AV Remote Control Target"

"Advanced Audio Source"

"Android Network Access Point"

"Android Network User"

"Handsfree Gateway"

"Headset Gateway"

"IcService_New"

"OBEX Object Push"

"OBEX Phonebook Access Server"

"SMS/MMS"

Again, any tips/tricks of advice would be greatly appreciated...again, I am in search of the HANDLE that will let me call BluetoothGATTGetServices.

Thank you.

Comment: You mixed up absolutely different things: GATT, Bluetooth LE and Classic Bluetooth. The very first thing you must do is to decide which one your application must use.

Comment: Hi Mike.  Thanks.  To start, I want to implement GATT for Bluetooth LE.  I thought I was going down that path correctly but can you give me some more information on which part is 'Classic Bluetooth'?  I am thinking I will have more coverage if I start with GATT for Bluetooth LE.  I didn't even know that classic Bluetooth supported GATT but I am no expert.  Thanks again sir.

Comment: BluetoothEnumerateInstalledServices is classic Bluetooth API. BluetoothGATTGetServices is legacy GATT API. On Win 10 you should use WinRT. Or, if you would like to stay with legacy API, use Setup API to find the services handler. More about GATT: https://www.btframework.com/gatt.htm

Comment: updated original because I couldn't edit this comment ???

Comment: As I wrote you are trying to use legacy BLE API. On Win 10 you should use WinRT API to communicate with BLE devices.